# Unable to delete resource after overriding devise registrations controller

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have followed this devise [how to: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29).

I have created a new RegistrationsController

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     ...
   end

   def destroy
      logger.debug 'destroy user'
      ...
   end
end
```

I have changed routes.rb :

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } do
  get 'users', :to => 'profile#index', :as => :user_root
end
```

and moved `devise/registrations/` views under my new RegistrationsController.

With `rake routes` I have :

```
DELETE /users(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"registrations"}
```

`after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` is working.

But `destroy` action doesn't work : when I cancel my account

```
<%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "ok?", :method => :delete %>
```

I have the following error :

`The action 'destroy' could not be found for RegistrationsController`

I use Devise 1.4.5 & Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Moving the destroy method to the non private section of the controller fixed it.